# req.logout, what parameters must I pass in request

Tags: node.js, qt, sails.js

My server is running on sailsjs.. it has a logout function as follows:

```
logout: function(few, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.cookie("jwttoken","0");
  res.json({"error":""});
}
```

I am writing a QT program which requires me to authenticate user.. I managed to authenticate using login by passing username and password into the body of the request.. what exactly do I need to pass to request for the logout to be successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. Carelessness on my part. Passing the username in the request body worked.